# Unable to full text search in Solr

Tags: search, solr

I have some data in solr. I want to search which name is `Chinmay Sahu` See below I have 3 results in output. But I got 3 instead of 1. Because Content `name` searched partially.

I want to full search those name having `Chinmay Sahu` only that contents will come.

**Output:**

```
"docs": [
      {
        "id": "741fde46a654879949473b2cdc577913",
        "content_id": "1277",
        "name": "Chinmay Sahu",
        "_version_": 1596995745829879800
      },
      {
        "id": "4e98d680efaab3afe051f3ddc00dc5f2",
        "content_id": "1825",
        "name": "Chinmay Panda",
        "_version_": 1596995745829879800
      }
      {
        "id": "741fde46a654879949473b2cdc577913",
        "content_id": "1259",
        "name": "Sasmita Sahu",
        "_version_": 1596995745829879800
      }
]
```

**Query:**

```
name:Chinmay Sahu
```

**Expected :**

```
"docs": [
      {
        "id": "741fde46a654879949473b2cdc577913",
        "content_id": "1277",
        "name": "Chinmay Sahu",
        "_version_": 1596995745829879800
      },
]
```

Please help

Comment: I have also tried `name:Chinmay Sahu*`, `name:*Chinmay Sahu*`, `name:*Chinmay Sahu` same output coming. :(

Comment: It is full text, what you want is a full match (all terms), a phrase match (all terms with a certain proximity), or an exact match.

Comment: @EricLavault All term match

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this

```
name:"Chinmay Sahu"
```

You need to do a phrase query to match the exact name.

I am guessing in your case the name field is using Standard tokenizer which will split tokens if whitespace is there. So while indexing in all the 3 docs there will be a token called "chinmay".

While you search using

```
name:Chinmay Sahu
```

Solr will search it like this since if there is no fieldName specified before a token solr automatically searches it in default_field.(however default field is removed from solr 7.3, So it depends on what version of solr are you using.
)

```
Name:chinmay AND default_field:sahu
```

So since all the three docs are having chinmay as a token in the index,the query will match all 3 docs.

Now i dont know what your default field is? can you post your solr schema? That way we can explain why you are seeing those 3 docs.

Answer (score 1):

Since root545 already explained that `field:foo bar` will search for `foo` in `field` and `bar` in the default search field, I'll suggest that it seems like you don't want to concern yourself with the exact Lucene syntax for searching. The edismax query parser is well suited for separating the typed search string from what fields are being searched and whether you want all tokens to match.

The query in that case would be just `Chinmay Sahu`, while you'd set `q.op=AND` (all terms must match), `defType=edismax` (use the edismax query parser) and `qf=name` (search the name field):

```
q=Chinmay Sahu&q.op=AND&defType=edismax&qf=name
```

You can also tune the different phrase parameters to make sure that names with the tokens in the exact same sequence will be boosted higher than those that have them in the opposite sequence (i.e. Sahu Chinmay).

If this is a programmatic search where no user is actually typing in the suggestion, using a phrase search as suggested is the way to go (`name:"Chinmay Sahu"`).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using query like

`name:(Chinmay Sahu)`

And make sure default operator is `AND` either in settings or query string like `q.op=AND`

With that approach you can use user input much easier since you don't need to parse it too much.